# Possible vandalism

Tags: discussion

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057456/smash) appears to be messing with other users by directly copying the code from their question and pasting it into answers...

This one is literally a direct copy:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22741852/1947286

Some of the others look like direct copies with meaningless changes like changing variable names:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22741499/1947286
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22741883/1947286

Are these just bad answers or is this a form of trolling that has managed to slide under the radar?

Comment: Just flag the user for moderator attention.

Comment: @Bart I dropped a flag already. I think there are a few more of the meaningless change type, but they're in languages that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: also downvote that answer

Comment: Had a look at the links myself and have flagged them too. They are definitely unconstructive answers.

Comment: Interesting that it was all on one day in the span of about two hours.

Comment: Deleting/downvoting seems like an appropriate response.  Those who have the power to delete, the time is now.  Flagging is a good thing to do when one establishes a pattern, as well.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I hadn't noticed that, perhaps this was some sort of rage quitting

Comment: This one looks like its just an unrelated wall of code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22741326/1947286

Comment: I'm looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22741883/1947286 side-by-side with the code from the question; there seem to be substantial changes, even if they're wrong from a "solution to the problem" standpoint.

Comment: looks like every answer is trolling answer

Comment: @JoshCaswell I think its been deleted

Comment: @JoshCaswell That was definitely a troll answer. It changed to 1-based array indexing and switched a bunch of correct backslashes to incorrect forward slashes.

Comment: I'm looking into this...

Comment: Can someone sanity check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22742024/168175 please. I don't understand why it was accepted.

Comment: @Flexo, there is no sanity there.  The accepted answer has jack to do with the question.  It not only doesn't answer it, it is perhaps the exact opposite of a valid answer for that question in every single possible way.

Comment: @Flexo The question should be closed as off-topic anyways. Lacks sufficient information to diagnose.

Comment: I agree on both the above comments, @Flexo. I went ahead and deleted that and closed the question.

Comment: Heh, he was already suspended

Comment: Could be someone probing the mechanics of the site in preparation for an attack or exploit.